# Как превратить строку в формулу?

Tags: java, алгоритм, swing

Допустим, я прошу пользователя ввести любую формулу графика, для простоты пусть это будет

```
"y = x^n" где n — любая степень, которую может ввести пользователь
```

Строку можно получить так:

```
 String str = formulafield.getText();
 str.toLowerCase();
 String [] arr = str.split("y = ");
 String formula = arr[0];
```

можно заменить `"^"` на `"pow(r,"`

```
formula.replaceAll("^", "pow(r,");
```

Получится строка

```
 "xpow(r,n"
```

Затем находим символы.

```
int xIndex = formula.indexOf('x');
int commaIndex = formula.indexOf(',');
```

Затем заменяем `'r' на 'x'`

```
formula.replase('r', 'x');
if(xIndex==0){
formula.replace('x','');
}
```

получим строку

```
 "pow(x,n"
```

Далее добавим к этой строке скобку и точку с запятой

```
 String fullformula = formula.concat(");");
```

Можно ли как-то получившуюся строку

```
 "pow(x,n);"
```

Превратить в

```
 Math.pow(x, n); ?
```

Подскажите алгоритм

Comment: String str = "2^3"; String[] split = str.split("^"); double result = Math.pow(Double.valueOf(split[0]), Double.valueOf(split[1])); - в чем, собственно, вопрос то?

Comment: @Дмитрий в том что формула может быть любой

Comment: @Konstantin_SH то что там может быть любая формула - это ограничение поставленной задачи? или Вы сами себе такое ограничение сделали?

Comment: @Tsyklop задача состоит в том чтобы уметь отрисовывать график любой функции. Соответственно формула должна быть любая

Comment: @Tsyklop иначе зачем ее вводить строкой, когда можно в программе ввести какую-то конкретную.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH Ну дык сделайте список формул которые могут быть. Я ж не думаю что их там 100500 штук. Если задача не поставлена как "Есть поле для ввода формул и нужно спарсить формулу и график построить", то вы можете делать как угодно.

Comment: @Tsyklop вот это "как угодно" я и пытаюсь узнать в своем вопросе)) Нашел класс .ScriptEngineManager но он мне NullPointerException выбрасывает какую бы формулу (с неизвестными или без) я бы не вводил.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH Вы сами себе усложняете задачу. зачем? что бы что? создайте `enum` с формулами. Создайте классы, которые процессят формулы в стиле ООП.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать exp4j https://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/

```
String str = formulafield.getText();
str.toLowerCase();
String [] arr = str.split("y = ");
String formula = arr[0];
Expression e = new ExpressionBuilder(formula)
.variables("x")
.build()
.setVariable("x", 2.3);
double result = e.evaluate();
```

Это отработанная вещь вычисление выражений.